# NPM Unmet Dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, npm, dependencies

I'd like to start off by saying I know there is a ton of post about this both here on SO and all over the web but i tried every solution and nothing is helping.

I'm building a package of React Native components to be used in several other React Native projects. Ideally all the other teams would have to do is add the dependency to their apps and run `npm install`. I've added this package as a dependency on a test React Native app to try it out but after running `npm install` I check `npm list` and it tells me that I have unmet dependencies.

Initially this was my package's `package.json`:

```
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-viro": "2.14.0"
  }
```

I then changed it to:

```
    "dependencies": {
      "react": "16.8.3",
      "react-native": "0.59.3",
      "react-viro": "2.14.0"
    }
```

I've even tried shrinking it to:

```
    "dependencies": {
      "react-viro": "2.14.0"
    }
```

And this is the `package.json` from the test app:

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.3",
    "my-lib": "file:../my-lib"
}
```

But after `npm install` and `npm list` i get:

```
npm ERR! missing: react@16.8.3, required by my-lib@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: react-native@0.59.3, required by my-lib@1.0.0
npm ERR! missing: react-viro@2.14.0, required by my-lib-@1.0.0
```

(or just the last line when only that one is declared as a dependency in my-lib).

Of course when running the app in the android simulator, as soon as the app loads, it complains it cannot find my library, pointing to [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968), but i tried every solution suggested there and nothing works, i've also tried deleting the `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` and then installing again, nothing works and this is driving me crazy this should be fairly simple what am I missing here?

Note: NPM is the latest version (6.9.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out there was nothing wrong with my configurations, the problem comes from an [unsolved NPM bug](https://npm.community/t/npm-install-for-package-with-local-dependency-fails/754/27) (at least at the time of this writing) related to local dependencies (`file:..`), i've uploaded that module to NPM, pulled the dependency from there and after running `npm install` there were no more unmet dependencies.